# How to create multiple file paths with nested directories?

Tags: python, for-loop, os.walk

I have the following setup in a directory named `apartments`:

```
apartments:
 |_Blue
     |__apartmentBlue1.xml
        apartmentBlue2.xml
        apartmentBlue3.xml
        nonsense.txt
  |_Red
      |_apartmentRed1.xml
        apartmentRed2.xml
        apartmentRed3.xml
  |_nonsense
```

I'm trying to get the file path for every file in every directory if that file ends with `.xml`

**This is my code:**

```
source: c:\data\desktop\buildingX\appartments

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:
        for diro in dirs:
            if file.endswith('.xml'):
                file_path = os.path.join(source, diro, file)
                print(file_path)
```

This gives me the desired output but I'm worried about the fact that my for loop is to nested, I would like to do more things with those paths but I feel like the further I nest it the more problems I will get. Are there any other ways to get it the file paths in a more compact way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `glob` built-in module

I have this directory structure

```
tree input_folder/
 input_folder
└──  year=2020
   ├──  month=08
   │  ├──  day=02
   │  │  ├──  hour=03
   │  │  │  └──  input.txt
   │  │  ├──  hour=04
   │  │  │  └──  input.txt
   │  │  ├──  hour=05
   │  │  │  └──  input.txt
   │  │  └──  hour=06
   │  │     └──  input.txt
   │  └──  day=03
   │     ├──  hour=03
   │     │  └──  input.txt
   │     ├──  hour=04
   │     │  └──  input.txt
   │     ├──  hour=05
   │     │  └──  input.txt
   │     └──  hour=06
   │        └──  input.txt
   └──  month=09
      └──  day=02
         ├──  hour=03
         │  └──  input.txt
         └──  hour=04
            └──  input.txt
```

You can get all of these files using this

```py
In [1]: from glob import glob

In [2]: glob("input_folder/**/*.txt", recursive=True)
Out[2]:
['input_folder/year=2020/month=09/day=02/hour=03/input.txt',
 'input_folder/year=2020/month=09/day=02/hour=04/input.txt',
 'input_folder/year=2020/month=08/day=03/hour=05/input.txt',
 'input_folder/year=2020/month=08/day=03/hour=03/input.txt',
 'input_folder/year=2020/month=08/day=03/hour=04/input.txt',
 'input_folder/year=2020/month=08/day=03/hour=06/input.txt',
 'input_folder/year=2020/month=08/day=02/hour=05/input.txt',
 'input_folder/year=2020/month=08/day=02/hour=03/input.txt',
 'input_folder/year=2020/month=08/day=02/hour=04/input.txt',
 'input_folder/year=2020/month=08/day=02/hour=06/input.txt']
```

In your case it should be

```py
glob(os.path.join(source,"**", "*.xml"), recursive=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
import glob

mydir = r '/home/'

for filename in glob.iglob(mydir + '**/*.py', recursive = True):
  print(filename)
```